# How come when $2^{k} | (x-1)(x+1)$ one of the terms is divisible by $2$ and not by $4$ when $k \in \mathbb{N} $ and $3 \leq k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

So I'm reading Knuth's 'Discrete Mathematics' at the moment and there's a paragraph detailing how many solutions are there for $x^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

So other cases (when $p$ is an odd prime or when p is equal to $2$ or $4$) are clear to me, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the case when $p=2^{k}$ with $3 \leq k$.

Here's what's troubling me

> If $2^{k}|(x - 1)(x + 1)$ then either $(x - 1)$
>   or $(x + 1)$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$, so the other one must be divisible
>   by $2^{k-1}$.

How come? I don't see that at all...

Comment: What exactly don't you see? The statement in the gray box looks like $(A\implies B)\implies C$. What don't you understand?

Comment: I don't see how he knows that one of them is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$. I see how that would implicate the $C$ in your implication, I just don't see the implication $(A \Rightarrow B)$.

Comment: Intuitively, numbers divisible by $4$ come up every four numbers: $4, 8, 12, 16, 20$, inbetween there are other even numbers which aren't divisible by $4$. **Edit:** $A$ is $2^k\mid (x-1)(x+1)$ and $B$ is that either $(x - 1)$
or $(x + 1)$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$.

Comment: So why $(x-1)$ or $(x+1)$ can't be divisible by $4$?

Comment: It can be divisible by $4$, just let $x=5$ and $k=3$. I think you might be misunderstanding the gray box. Do you want me to formalize it for you?

Comment: Yes please. I just don't see how $A$ implicates $B$ which seems to be the case here...

Comment: With given conditions.. Do you atleast see either of $x+1$ or $x-1$ is divided by $2$???

Comment: $x-1$ and $x+1$ are two integers with a difference of $2$. Since their product is even, the two integers are even. If $x-1 = 4m$, then $x+1 = 4m+2$, and that means $x+1$ is divisible by $2$, but not by $4$. If on the other hand $x-1$ is not divisible by $4$, then we laso have one of the two numbers divisible by $2$ but not by $4$.

Comment: Thank you! I missed the fact that they are both even and that clouded my thinking.

Comment: Do you understand that, once formalized, the $A\implies B$ part says: $\forall k,x\in \Bbb N\left(2^k\mid (x-1)(x+1)\implies \exists y\in \{x-1, x+1\}(2\mid y \land 4\not \mid y)\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are cases in which neither $x+1$ nor $x-1$ is divisible by $2$ (take $x$ to be an even number).

It is given that $2^k | (x+1)(x-1) $.

Suppose neither $x+1$ nor $x-1$ is divided by $2$, then $2$ does not divide $(x+1)(x-1)$. So, there is no point of considering $2^k | (x+1)(x-1)$.

So, without loss of generality, suppose $2$ divides $x+1$

suppose both $(x+1)$ and $(x-1)$ are divisible by $4$ then, we should have $2^{2m} |(x+1)(x-1) $ which need not be the case always... (it is not specified that power of $2$ is even)

So, we can suppose $x+1$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$.

So, we should have $2^{k-1} | (x+1)$